# Hbase client can't connect to remote Hbase server

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

i have written a following hbase client class for remote server:

```
System.out.println("Hbase Demo Application ");

            // CONFIGURATION

                // ENSURE RUNNING
            try {
                HBaseConfiguration config = new HBaseConfiguration();
                config.clear();
                config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.15.20");
                config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
                config.set("hbase.master", "192.168.15.20:60000");
                //HBaseConfiguration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    //config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");  // Here we are running zookeeper locally
                HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);


                System.out.println("HBase is running!");
            //  createTable(config);    
                //creating a new table
                HTable table = new HTable(config, "mytable");
                System.out.println("Table mytable obtained ");  
                addData(table);
            } catch (MasterNotRunningException e) {
                System.out.println("HBase is not running!");
                System.exit(1);
            }catch (Exception ce){ ce.printStackTrace();
```

it is throwing some exception:

```
Oct 17, 2011 1:43:54 PM org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation getMaster
INFO: getMaster attempt 0 of 1 failed; no more retrying.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:883)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC$Invoker.invoke(HBaseRPC.java:257)
    at $Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1215)
    at com.ifkaar.hbase.HBaseDemo.main(HBaseDemo.java:31)
HBase is not running!
```

can you tell me why is it throwing an exception, what is wrong with code and how to solve it.

Comment: Please accept answers for your old questions before asking new questions. No one would be willing to answer your questions since you are not giving any feedback.

Comment: ok. from now on i will. i was new user to this site.normally i do vote for the answer which helps me.Thank you

Comment: `config.set("hbase.master", "192.168.15.20:60000");` 

can you comment out this line and try again ?

Comment: i have tried again but the result is same.

Comment: can you telnet 192.168.15.20:2181 (is there a connection issue?)

Comment: it is connecting to destination(server).

Comment: @AliRaza I think you should accept this answer if you find it helpful..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This problem is occuring due to your HBase server's hosts file. 
You just need to edit you HBase server's /etc/hosts file. 
Remove the localhost entry from that file and put the localhost entry in front of HBase server IP.

For example, your HBase server's `/etc/hosts` files seems like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.166.66.66 xyz.hbase.com hbase
```

You have to change it like this by removing localhost:

```
# 127.0.0.1 localhost # line commented out
192.166.66.66 xyz.hbase.com hbase localhost # note: localhost added here
```

This is because when remote machine asks hbase server machine where HMaster is running, it tells that it is running on localhost. 
So if the entry is 127.0.0.1 then HBase server returns this address and remote machine start to find HMaster on its own machine (locally). 
When we change that with the HBase Server IP then everything works fine :)

Comment: Hbase must be restarted after the change. 'netstat -a | grep 6000' command is helpful here as it shows that master binds to the local interface.

Comment: Is there any elegant way to do that? Can we specify the xyz.hbase.com in some configuration file instead of changing the hosts file? Thanks. This solution actually works for me, but not that elegant.

Comment: Who ever understands, what he is trying to say. Please edit this Post to make it readable.

Comment: @seb he says "remove the 127.0.0.1 line and add localhost to the real ip address line"

Comment: But, after removing 127.0.0.1 and adding localhost to the ip address, the ssh is not establishing connection ("ssh username@ip-addr" and "ssh username@localhost" both gives 'connection closed by remote host') to restart the hbase instance. Do anyone know what could be issue?

Comment: hasn't this essentially renamed "localhost" to "192.166.66.66", and now every other application which tries to use "localhost" from that computer will end up going out to the network and back again?

Answer (score 2):

I agree.. The HBase is very sensitive to /etc/hosts configurations..  I had to set the zeekeeper bindings property in the hbase-site.xml correctly in order for the above mentioned Java code to work...For example: I had to set it as follows:

```
{property}
  {name}hbase.zookeeper.quorum{/name}
  {value}www.remoterg12.net{/value}      {!-- this is the externally accessible domain --}
{/property}
{property}
  {name}hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort{/name}
  {value}2181{/value}              {!-- everything needs to be externally accessible --}
{/property}
{property}
  {name}hbase.master.info.port{/name}    {!--   http://www.remoterg12.net:60010/ --}
  {value}60010{/value}
{/property}
{property}
  {name}hbase.master.info.bindAddress{/name}
  {value}www.remoterg12.net{/value}      {!-- Use this to access the GUI console, --}
{/property}
```

The Remote GUI will give you a clear picture of the Binding Domains..  For example, the [HBase Master]  property in the "GUI Web console" should be something like this: www.remoterg12.net:60010  (It should NOT be localhost:60010 )... AND YES!!, I did have to play around with the /etc/hosts just right as I didn't want to mess up the existing Apache configs :-)

Answer (score 0):

The same problem can be solve by editing the `conf/regionservers` file in hbase directory to add the Hbase server (Remote) in it . Then no need to change the etc/hosts file

After editing `conf/regionservers` will look like:

```
localhost  
ip address of the remote hbase server
```

eg

```
localhost              
10.132.258.366
```

Comment: Could you please explain this approach in more Details? I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: this doesn't seems to work editig the /etc/host file only makes hbase remote clients to work

Answer (score 0):

Exact same problem here with HBase 1.1.3.
2 virtuals machines (Ubuntu) on the same network. The logs show that the client can reach Zookeeper but not the HBase server.

TL;DR: remove the following line in `/etc/hosts` on the server (*server_hostame*):

```
127.0.1.1 server_hostname server_hostname
```

And add this one with `127.x.y.z` the ip of your server on the (local) network:

```
192.x.y.z server_hostname
```

I tried a lot of combinations on the client and server sides. In standalone mode I don't think there is a better approach.
Not really proud of that. It is a shame to have to mess with the network configuration and to not even provide a HBase shell client able to connect remotely to a server (welcome to the Java world of illusions...)

On the server side, leave the files `conf/hbase-site.xml` empty. You don't need to put a Zookeeper configuration in here, defaults are fine.
Same for `etc/regionservers`. Leave it with the default entry (*localhost*) because I don't think in standalone mode it really cares (and I tried to put `server_hostname` in it and of course this does not works).

On the client side, It must know the server by hostname if you want to resolve with it so again add an entry in your `/etc/hosts` client file for the server.

As a bonus I give you my `sbt` configuration and some **complete** working code for the client since the HBase team seems to have spent the documentation budget at Vegas for the last 4 years (again, welcome the «Business ready» world of Java/Scala).

*build.sbt*:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "1.1.2",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.1.2",
)
```

*some_client_code.scala*:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HTable, Put, HBaseAdmin}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "server_hostname")
HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(hbaseConf)

val table = new HTable(hbaseConf, "my_hbase_table")
val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row_key"))
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("colId1"), Bytes.toBytes("foo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late to answer this question but I want to share my way of resolving a similar issue.

I had the same issue and I tried to set the zookeeper quorum from the java program and also tried via the CLI but none of them worked.

I am using CDH 5.7.7 with HBase version 1.1.0
Finally I had to export few configs to the Hadoop classpath to fix the issue. Here is config that I have exported.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/share/cmf/lib/cdh5/hbase-protocol-0.98.1-cdh5.5.0.jar:/etc/hbase/conf:/driven/conf
```

Hope this helps.