# hbase refusing connection for remote user

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hadoop, hbase

Hi I am new to hbase and hadoop.I have properly setup them but check them from same machine and it is working fine.Now when tried to connect from a java client remotly  , this exception is coming.I really need help please guide me about this. Exception is given below:

```
/04/17 17:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=xyz
12/04/17 17:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/xyz
12/04/17 17:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/opt/xyz/hbase-sample
12/04/17 17:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.15.169:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
12/04/17 17:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /192.168.15.169:2181
12/04/17 17:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to hbase.xyz.com/192.168.15.169:2181, initiating session
12/04/17 17:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server hbase.xyz.com/192.168.15.169:2181, sessionid = 0x136c00d59ac0009, negotiated timeout = 180000
12/04/17 17:41:36 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 0 of 1 failed; no more retrying.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:604)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:328)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:883)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:750)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC$Invoker.invoke(HBaseRPC.java:257)
at $Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:393)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:444)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:360)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1258)
at HBaseDemo.main(HBaseDemo.java:55)
HBase is not running!
Execution script exiting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer.I found the problem and solve it by just removing the localhost entry from my /etc/hosts .

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread:

[Hbase client do not able to connect with remote Hbase server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791788/hbase-client-do-not-able-to-connect-with-remote-hbase-server)

You can try to telnet to the machine you want to connect at port no 60000,

also check if that port is open.