# Hbase:This server is in the failed servers list: localhost/127.0.0.1:38812

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to connect to a remote HBase server. The remote server is running on Ubuntu and is running fine and able to access it using Hbase client(shell) as well as a Java Client. However, when I am trying to connect to that server from a Windows machine using the same java client

```
 org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration hadoopConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
 hadoopConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "Paras-Lenovo");
```

I am getting following error:

```
27 May, 2013 4:03:50 PM org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper <init>
INFO: The identifier of this process is 2964@RDUBEY-PC
27 May, 2013 4:03:51 PM org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation shouldRetryGetMaster
INFO: getMaster attempt 0 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 1007
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupConnection(HBaseClient.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:974)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
    at $Proxy19.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:126)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.hadoop.HadoopSession.start(HadoopSession.java:95)
    at com.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger.start(NoSqlRawLogger.java:291)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstanceImpl(BootstrapImpl.java:55)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:36)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:65)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:60)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:57)
    at com.alvazan.ssql.cmdline.PlayOrm.main(PlayOrm.java:98)
27 May, 2013 4:03:52 PM org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation shouldRetryGetMaster
INFO: getMaster attempt 1 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 1005
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: localhost/127.0.0.1:38812
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:425)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:974)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
    at $Proxy19.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:126)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.hadoop.HadoopSession.start(HadoopSession.java:95)
    at com.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger.start(NoSqlRawLogger.java:291)
```

Please note that the entries in window's host file is fine and I am able to telnet 60010 and 2181 port of hbase/zookeper ports from Windows machine so the issue is not because of connectivity. The question [Hbase client do not able to connect with remote Hbase server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791788/hbase-client-do-not-able-to-connect-with-remote-hbase-server) is similar to this but that is also not resolving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error today while accessing hbase from client remotely and finally got it resolved. Just posting the workaround for the benefit of others.

The libraries I used for the hbase java client in the remote system were different than those in the hadoop systems. The issue got resolved once i used the same set of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

disable the ipv6 setting of the machine that has the hbase server.then every thing will be ok.I had the identical problem bofore.

Comment: I also found this Link can you look into this :
http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/hbase-error-this-server-is-in-the-failed-servers-list/

Answer (score 0):

I find this discussion thread useful http://apache-hbase.679495.n3.nabble.com/Where-is-HBase-failed-servers-list-stored-td4068803.html.

If you are sure that the IP's haven't changed and everything else is working fine with hbase shell then restart of master should help (Which was my case)